# Prove that if $e.d \equiv 1 \bmod (p-1)(q-1)$ then it’s impossible to have $e.d \equiv 1 \bmod pq$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, cryptography, totient-function

I am studying R.S.A. cryptosystem and here is the question that came to my mind. Let’s pick $p, q$ to be two primes and $n = p * q$. From that we calculate Euler’s totient function:

$$
\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1).
$$ Then we chose the public and private key pair as $e, d$ such that:
$$
e * d \equiv 1  \bmod \phi(n).
$$

Now I want to prove that for the same pair $(e, d)$ it no longer holds that:

$$
e * d \equiv 1 \bmod n.
$$

I have tried writing:
$$
e * d = k * \phi(n) + 1\\
e * d = l * n + 1,
$$
for some integer $k$ and $l$.
So it should be that:
$$
k * \phi(n) + 1 = l * n + 1 \\
k * \phi(n) = l * n. \\
$$
So replacing the values of $n = pq$ and $\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1)$ we get:
$$
k * (p - 1) * (q - 1) = l * p * q. 
$$
I sense that there is an impossibility. But can’t figure out what it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want $k  (p - 1)  (q - 1) = l  p q$, you could take $k=pq$ and $l=(p-1)(q-1)$, right?

Comment: I see, so how should I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

The statement you have given appears to be false. A counterexample which first strung to my mind is $e =  31$ and $d = 27791$. Taking $p = 89, q = 11$, we get $e*d$ congruent to both $1$ mod $(p*q)$ and $1$ mod $((p-1)*(q-1))$